# Multiple inline images, float text on each one

Tags: html, css

I have several images that are placed next to each other inside divs like so:

```
<div id='images'>
    <div class="iphoneimage">
        <img src="img1.jpg" height="300">
        <h5 class="size">1363 x 2048</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="iphoneimage">
        <img src="img1.jpg" height="300">
        <h5 class="size">1363 x 2048</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are styled with the following css:

```
.iphoneimage {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 169px;
    float: left;
}
img {
    position: relative;
}
h5.size { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 20px; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

I am trying to get the text to show over the top of each image, however currently only one set of text is showing over the first image.

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to `.iphoneimage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative` to the div `.iphoneimage`

```
.iphoneimage {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 169px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/cnH5Y/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.iphoneimage {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 169px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    position: relative;
}
h5.size { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 20px; 
    width: 100%; 
}

<div id='images'>
    <div class="iphoneimage">
        <img src="img1.jpg" height="300">
        <h5 class="size">1363 x 2048</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="iphoneimage">
        <img src="img1.jpg" height="300">
        <h5 class="size">1363 x 2048</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```